# Subset dataset by time criteria by ID

Tags: r, subset

I am dealing with a dataset which looks like this below

```
 Id           Time           Location
 754005       13:19:00       HK564
 754005       13:19:00       IE578
 980278       19:51:00       AK177
 980278       21:15:00       JB237
```

The `Id` column contains duplicate values, `Time` may or may not contain duplicates, and the `Location` column contains unique values.

I am trying to filter this dataset where the `Id` values are unique based on this logic:

1) If the time values are the same for that `Id`, then retain the last row for that `Id`. In other words, id `754005` is repeated twice, the times are the same but `Location` is different so retaining the last row means retaining this row

```
754005       13:19:00       IE578
```

2) If the time values are different for that `Id`, then retain the row with the latest time value for that `Id`. In other words, id `980278` has two different time values, `19:51:00`, `21:15:00`, retain the row with time `21:15:00` for this id because this is the latest time.

The final dataset should looks like this below

```
 Id           Time           Location
 754005       13:19:00       IE578
 980278       21:15:00       JB237
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by ordering the dataset by `Time` and by picking the last observation in each group. With `data.table` this becomes "one-liner":

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[order(Time), .SD[.N], by = Id]
```

> ```
>        Id     Time Location
> 1: 754005 13:19:00    IE578
> 2: 980278 21:15:00    JB237
> ```

Alternative, the `tail()` function can be used to pick the last observation in each group:

```
setDT(DF)[order(Time), tail(.SD, 1), by = Id]
```

#### Explanation

This solutions needs less lines of code than the other answers posted so far, especially the `data.table` code by [digEmAll](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51925864/3817004). So, I feel this deserves a detailed explanation:

- `setDT(DF)` coerces `DF` into a data.table object *by reference*, i.e., without copying while `as.data.table(DF)` creates a copy.
- `order(Time)` orders `Time` lexicographically. There is no need for converting the time string into something else for the purpose of sorting. Here, `Time` is a factor whose levels were ordered lexicographically while reading the dataset.
  According to the help page `help("order")`, *any unresolved ties will be left in their original ordering*. So, the order of rows for `Id == 754005`, e.g., will not be changed.
- `.SD` is the subset of rows for each group. `.N` is the number of rows in each group. So, `.SD[.N]` picks the last row of each group.

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DF <- fread("
 Id           Time           Location
 754005       13:19:00       HK564
 754005       13:19:00       IE578
 980278       19:51:00       AK177
 980278       21:15:00       JB237", 
data.table = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

`DF` is a data.frame with character columns turned into factors assuming the "worst case".

```
str(DF)
```

> ```
> 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  3 variables:
>  $ Id      : int  754005 754005 980278 980278
>  $ Time    : Factor w/ 3 levels "13:19:00","19:51:00",..: 1 1 2 3
>  $ Location: Factor w/ 4 levels "AK177","HK564",..: 2 3 1 4
> ```

Comment: Much smarter than my approach :)

Answer (score 0):

We can `group_by` `Id`, and `arrange` `Time` in `desc`ending order and select the last row from each group using `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  arrange(desc(hms(Time))) %>%
  slice(n())

#     Id    Time   Location
#   <int> <fct>    <fct>   
#1 754005 13:19:00 IE578   
#2 980278 21:15:00 JB237
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach using base R :

```
# recreate your input
DF <- read.table(text=
'Id           Time           Location
754005       13:19:00       HK564
754005       13:19:00       IE578
980278       19:51:00       AK177
980278       21:15:00       JB237',header=TRUE)

# convert time strings to datetimes
dates <- strptime(DF$Time,format='%H:%M:%S',tz='GMT')

# get the desired rows
DF2 <- 
DF[unique(
   ave(seq_len(nrow(DF)),DF$Id,
       FUN=function(i)i[order(dates[i],i,decreasing=TRUE)][1]
      )
   )
,]

# > DF2
#       Id     Time Location
# 2 754005 13:19:00    IE578
# 4 980278 21:15:00    JB237
```

Or using `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
# convert data.frame to data.table
DT <- as.data.table(DF)

# create column with time strings converted to ITime objects
DT[,TimeConverted := as.ITime(Time,format='%H:%M:%S')]

# group by Id and choose the right row
DT2 <- DT[,{.SD[order(TimeConverted,.I,decreasing=TRUE)[1]]},by=Id]

# remove TimeConverted column
DT2[,TimeConverted := NULL]

# > DT2
#        Id     Time Location
# 1: 754005 13:19:00    IE578
# 2: 980278 21:15:00    JB237
```